# Text goes out of TextFormField - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Faced such a problem that when I create a task and add 2 or more fields to it, then when transferring this text to another screen, it climbs out of the text field. I can't figure out what to do to fix the error. Hide extra text or increase the size of the TextFormField under the text. Please tell me how to solve this problem? Thank you.

**edit_todo**

```
class EditTodoScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final Todo todo;
  EditTodoScreen({Key? key, required this.todo}) : super(key: key);

  final _controller = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    _controller.text = todo.description;

    return BlocBuilder<TodoBloc, TodoState>(builder: (context, state) {
      return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text(
            'Edit Todo',
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
          ),
        ),
        body: _body(context),
      );
    });
  }

  Widget _body(context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          TextFormField(
            controller: _controller,
            autocorrect: true,
            decoration: const InputDecoration(hintText: 'Enter todo message'),
          ),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 10.0,
          ),
          InkWell(
            onTap: () {
              // BlocProvider.of<TodoBloc>(context)
              //     .add(UpdateTodos(Todo(description: _todoName)));
              final updateTodo = Todo(description: _controller.text);
              BlocProvider.of<TodoBloc>(context).add(
                UpdateTodos(
                  updateTodo,
                  // _controller.text,
                ),
              );
              Navigator.pop(context);
            },
            child: _updateBtn(context),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

 Widget _updateBtn(context) {
    return Container(
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      height: 50.0,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.black, borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)),
      child: Center(
        child: Text(
          'Update Todo',
          style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 17.0,
              color: Colors.amber.shade700,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

**todo_list**

```
onTap: () {
                      Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => EditTodoScreen(
                            todo: state.loadedUser[index],
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    },
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: What does your `_updateBtn` widget look like?

Comment: added widget _updateBtn

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/auto_size_text try this package

Comment: Wow. This is a discovery for me. Thanks a lot. Only the examples show how to use it with text, but if I pass a value (text) in the controller, then how do I wrap it in AutoSizeText?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could define max and min lines for `TextFormField`. I've used max lines of two here. Use whatever you find best for your case. If there are more lines than the maximum you've defined it will become scrollable.

```
TextFormField(
    controller: _controller,
    autocorrect: true,
    decoration: const InputDecoration(
        hintText: 'Enter todo message',
    ),
    maxLines: 2,
    minLines: 1,
),
```

Comment: It helped, thanks, but only if you add maxLines 2, if you add less or minLines, then the error does not go away.
Is it possible to add a slider on the side that shows what can be scrolled?

Comment: @MaxZubko I'm not sure if there is a way to customize `TextFormField` to somehow indicate to user that it is scrollable and I didn't find much while searching. You could ask another question regarding this. Maybe someone else would know a way.

Comment: @MaxZubko Technically you could check the text for newline characters or whether it is longer than a certain length. But the `TextFormField` itself doesn't seem to support a way to accomplish this.

Comment: Got it, but thanks for the help anyway :)